# how to resize Qlabel from both sides?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qlabel in middle of my main window. When I call its **adjustSize** function, it grows just from the right side. how to grow it from both sides? I want my text always be in the middle of the main window.

```cpp
|                |          |                |
|      ----------|          |   ----------   |
|      |my label||    ==>   |   |my label|   |
|      ----------|          |   ----------   |
|                |          |                |
```

Comment: add `your_label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);`

Comment: @eyllanesc I think it is for the text in Qlabel and not for Qlabel place in the main window. the text is always in the middle of the Qlabel, but Qlabel just grows from the right side.

Comment: The default text is aligned to `Qt::AlignLeft`, on the other hand if you are using a QVBoxLayout then when adding to the QLabel use `your_layout->addWidget(label, Qt::AlignCenter)`. Provide a [MRE]

Comment: In the example illustration you gave, you're not resizing the label. You're moving it around inside its parent widget. The label's width is 8 in both cases. So your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @eyllanesc your second suggestion works. but the true way is like this:  
     ```your_layout->addWidget(label,0,Qt::AlignCenter)```. thank you.

Comment: To better debug your problem, call `setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box);` on your label. This will draw a box around it so you can actually see whether the text really is in the middle of the label and how big it actually is.

Comment: @NikosC. thank you. eyllanesc suggestion helped me for solving my problem.